# $ [[[A,B],C],D] + [[[B,C],D],A] + [[[C,D],A],B] + [[[D,A],B],C] = 0 $

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

> If A and B are $n \times n$ matrices, define the Lie product $[A,B] = AB-BA$.

Exercise 1.37 of the book Basic Linear Algebra by T.S. Blyth and E.F. Robertson asks to prove that $$ (*) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  [[[A,B],C],D] + [[[B,C],D],A] + [[[C,D],A],B] + [[[D,A],B],C] = 0 $$ holds, but I couldn't prove it! Actually by expansion of the l.h.s of $(*)$ I reached to the point to show that $$[DB,AC] +[AC,BD] +[BD,CA] + [CA,DB] = 0$$ holds but I can't proceed any further.

Looks nice, I mean we can write like $$[D',A'] +[A',B'] +[B',C'] + [C',D'] = 0$$ and seeing 'neighboring' and 'cycling' but that doesn't become any simpler. 
Please help! Thank you.

Comment: I am not really sure about second equality...if you try to expand it the sum is not zero.

Comment: @Gianluca - the book says the sum is zero!

Comment: I mean the equality $[DB,AC] +[AC,BD] +[BD,CA] + [CA,DB] = 0$

Comment: @Gianluca - the equality in the book, (*) in OP, results in the equality [DB,AC]+[AC,BD]+[BD,CA]+[CA,DB]=0 ; means the book may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are counterexamples for the identity $(*)$, with
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
D=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & 1 \\ 0 & d_1 \end{pmatrix},\;
$$
for all $d_1\in K$, where $K$ is a field of characteristic zero. We have 
$$
[[[A,B],C],D] + [[[B,C],D],A] + [[[C,D],A],B] + [[[D,A],B],C] =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
What is true instead is the Malcev-identity
$$
[[A,B],[A,C]]=[[[A,B],C],A]+[[[B,C],A],A]+[[[C,A],A],B]
$$

Comment: What is K? Integers?

Comment: You can take integers, if you want. Usually the matrix algebra $M_n(K)$ is over a field $K$.

Comment: You are welcome!